# I want to move my menu bar to the top right

Tags: html, css, menu, move

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Roohi Health Screnning</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="roohiSTYLE.css">

        <!-- IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements --> <!--[if it IE 9]>
        <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"><script>
        <![endif]-->


    </head>
    <body>

    <div>
        <header>
            <h1>Roohisd page<h1> 
        </header>
        <section>
        <!-- Content Starts Here -->
        <header>
            <h1>Welcome to My Site</h1>
        </header>


        <div id="logo">
        <img src="images/Roohi-logo2.png">
        </div>

        <nav id="navigation">
            <ul id="navMain">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="currentPage"><a href="#"> Visit our site</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About us</a>

                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                </ul>
        </nav>





        <!-- Content Ends Here -->
        </section>

    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**:

```
body {
    background-image: url('images/backgorund-roohi.jpg');
}
#navMain {
    list-style: none;
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: 1px #a81b2f solid;
    float: right: width:940px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    4-webkit-border-radous: 5px;
}
#navMain > li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    border-right: 1px solid #9b2838;
}
#navMain > li > a {
    color: #f4e4e6;
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 11px 18px;
    border-right: 1px solid #bf3549;
}
#navMain a {
    background: rgb(99, 20, 32);
    background: rgb(99, 20, 32, 0.25);
}
#navMain ul {
    display: none;
}
#navMain ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    list-style: none;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-top: 1px #a81b2f solid;
    background#e8edee;
}
#navMain ul li a {
    color: 5d6364;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 6px 7px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d9da;
    border-left: 1px solid #d3d9da;
    border-right: 1px solid #d3d9da;
    font-size: 13px;
}
#navMain li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    top: 39px;
    min-width: 200px;
}
```

This is my code I want to move the menu to the top right of the page.  How do I do that?

I want the menu to be displayed on the top right. The menu is displaying on the bottom not as I want on the top right.

Comment: A fiddle would be nice.

Comment: Where do you want the nav bar? In the top right corner ordered vertically? Or just with the items floating against the right side?

Comment: Admiral Adama on the right

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/34tCu/

```
#navigation { position: absolute; top:0; right:0;}
```

please be more specific, if this is not what you had in mind.

Comment: nicht wirklich ich kann es nicht sehne irgendwas stimmt mit der Webseite nicht hier ist ein link mit den sachen kannst ja da versuchen bitte  http://ge.tt/2ArHs2i1/v/0

Comment: hi, natürlich werde ich jetzt deine zip datei herunterladen, auspacken und darin deinen code für dich schreiben, aber wir können es gerne hier oder bei jsfiddle probieren. was willst du denn genau erreichen? möchtest du vielleicht, dass das menü oberhalb der roten line und auf der rechten seite positioniert wird?

Comment: in dem fall müsstest du dem #navmain die genaue höhe des menüs hinzuzufügen (also `height: 38px;`) und aus `border: 1px #a81b2f solid;` in `border-bottom: 1px #a81b2f solid;` zu ändern. dann noch den border radius rausnehmen und float left zu right ändern. das ergebnis siehst du hier: http://jsfiddle.net/34tCu/2/

Comment: cool hast du ne email adresse doer so wo ich dich erreichen koennte falls ich noch mehr fragen habe bin neu zu html and css

Comment: was ich will ist das das meunu oben rechts auf der seite kommt